# Ownership conditional in a belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations, conditional-statements

I have two models: `Users` and `Posts`. The way I have things setup, a post belongs to an owner (i.e. user) and also has many participants (i.e. users). In my User model I'd like to ensure that an `owner` never belongs to a `post`. I've done this in the front-end but found more code than need-be.

This led me to believe that using `conditions` would be an ideal solution. I've seen SQL conditions used in this manner but didn't know exactly what the best way to get this done for an ownership scenario. Suggestions?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  # belongs_to :posts, conditions: ...
end

class Post
  has_many :participants, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
end
```

Comment: I don't understand the sentence : 
I'd like to ensure that an owner never belongs to a post
Do you mean that you don't want an owner of a post to be a participant to another post ?

Comment: Close but no. For one particular post, I don't want the `owner` to also be a `participant`.

Comment: Oh got it, give me 5 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is probably an error in your associations, cause it seems like you need a join table for the participants relationship.
You should probably use a http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association
has_many through association.

Something like this :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :owned_post, class_name: "Post", foreign_key: :owner_id
  has_many :participations
  has_many :posts, through: :participations
end

class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :participant, class_name: "User"
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User"
  has_many :participants, through: :participations
end
```

When you have this model, you can use a validation on the participation model to prevent an owner to be a participant. By using a custom validation : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :participant, class_name: "User"
  validate :participant_is_not_the_owner

  def participant_is_not_the_owner
    if participant == post.owner
      errors.add(:participant, "can't be the owner")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your models are basically the same as my answer. But I didn't use a validation (which is probably the easiest thing). I tried to answer the question of the condition on the belongs_to. My lambda will filter out all owners from the participants.

Comment: Yep, I was writing at the same time you answered. But I think the validation is more appropriate cause you don't save the participation of the owner in the database. I think he does not want to filter the owners from the participants but not to have any owner in the participants. Not sure I'm clear...

Answer (score 3):

To acheive this, I think you need a third model. If you set things up as follows it should work:

**User model:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts  # This is the other side of your owner association
  has_many :user_posts  # This is your link table for participants
  has_many :participations, through: :user_posts, source: :user # These are the posts the user is a participant in
end
```

**Post model:**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_posts, ->(p) { where.not(user_id: p.user_id) } # Here is your condition for the participants
  has_many :participants, through: :user_posts, source: :user
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
end
```

**UserPost model:**

```
class UserPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

As @Oxynum's answer makes clear, you should also think about putting a validation in the UserPost model to prevent the participant from being saved if he is also the owner:

```
validate :participant_cannot_be_owner

  def participant_cannot_be_owner
    if user == post.try(:owner)
      errors.add(:user_id, "can't be the owner of the post")
    end
  end
```

Comment: In your answer, you still allow a user to create a user_post with the owner, it becomes invisible to the association :user_posts but it is still created in the database.

Comment: :-) I just said that same thing on your answer @Oxynum. Two ways to achieve the same result basically

Comment: Upvoted anyway, it is useful to understand the difference

Comment: Thanks! I up voted yours, and also edited my answer, because I think your validation makes it more complete.